# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias in laravel -{5.7}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Iam a new beginer of laravel.
Now, Iam learning relationship part of laravel.
I see many question like it !! But no answer is not good for me.
I see this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_education_iteams' (SQL: select * from `tbl_education_iteams` inner join `tbl_education_iteams` on `tbl_education_groups`.`id` = `tbl_education_iteams`.`group`)
```

I wrote my Query in Controller :

```
$education_iteam = DB::table('tbl_education_iteams')
->join('tbl_education_iteams','tbl_education_groups.id','=','tbl_education_iteams.group')
        ->select()
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to join a table to itself. Because of this, your SQL database does not know which version of the table to refer to; the one on the left side of the join, or the right. You need to give the table reference on one side of the join an alias so that knows which side you want data from.

```
DB::table('tbl_education_iteams')
->join('tbl_education_iteams as other_iteams', 'tbl_education_groups.id', '=', 'other_iteams.group')
->select('other_items.*')
...
```

Note that with your select statement, you'll need to be explicity about which fields from which table to want to get.

Comment: i see now another error    `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'paroshi.other_items' (SQL: select `other_items`.* from `tbl_education_iteams` inner join `tbl_education_iteams` as `other_iteams` on `tbl_education_groups`.`id` = `other_iteams`.`group`)`

Comment: EDIT: Just realised there was a typo in my answer, where I had written "items" instead of "iteams". Just fix the spelling in the select. The error you received should have given you a hint as to what was wrong.

Comment: i see now another error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tbl_education_groups.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `other_iteams`.* from `tbl_education_iteams` inner join `tbl_education_iteams` as `other_iteams` on `tbl_education_groups`.`id` = `other_iteams`.`group`)`

Comment: i have `id` column in `tbl_education_groups`